# Can't we say that on a commutative ring every ideal is prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

On a commutative ring K, an ideal I is prime when:
$$
    I \text{ is a subgroup of }K,\text{ }  I \neq K, \text{and if } x,y \in K, \text{the relation } xy \in I \text{ implies } x \in I \text{ or }y\in I.
$$

But is this not always the case in a commutative ring K?
Because by definition, if  I is an ideal of K, we have $ax \in I$ for any $a \in K$ and $x \in I$.

Where my understanding went wrong?

Comment: What you wrote is **not** the definition of "primary ideal" but of **prime ideal** ...and anyway the answer is no.

Comment: sorry it was a translation problem.

Comment: Consider $\mathbb{Z}$ and the ideal $6\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\;2\cdot 3\in6\Bbb Z\;$ . Yet $\;2,\,3\notin 6\Bbb Z\;$

I think the understanding problem here is: a prime ideal certainly fulfills the condition$\;xy\in I\implies (x\in I\;\;or\;\;y\in I\,$) , and this is **not** the same as the very definition of *ideal*, as the example above shows: observe that

$$a\in6\Bbb Z\implies a=6m,\,m\in\Bbb Z\implies\;\;\forall\,y\in\Bbb Z\;,\;\;ay=6my\in\Bbb Z$$

Answer (score 2):

You wrote the definition of a **prime** ideal, and no, it is not the same as the later thing you wrote. Here is a side-by side comparison of the two:

1. $\forall x,y\in K$, if $xy\in I$, then $x\in I\text{ or } y\in I$
2. $\forall x\in I\, \forall y\in K$, we have $xy\in I$

The first one is a conclusion about the factors of a product, and the second one is a conclusion about a product.

In fact, it's a basic theorem that all proper ideals of a commutative ring are prime iff the ring is a field. See for example Kaplansky's *Commutative rings* chapter 1, exercise 1, page 7, or most other introductory commutative algebra texts.